# Objective C, Can't load an image from data returned by ASIHTTP request

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:[request responseData]];
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];


    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc ]imageWithData:data];//it blows up here
    self.q.image = img;

    [img release];
    self.request = nil;
    [delegate imageDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView];

}
```

I am downloading an image data using ASIHTTP request and it worked fine. But If I try to create an image using the data from ASIHTTP request then it blows up..What is the problem?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: How does it blow up? What exception do you get? What value has `data` before the call to `imageWithData:`? How have you confirmed that `data` indeed contains valid image data?

Comment: uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage imageWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e3a660'  I am getting this error and the data value look ok..It is too long to add here but it has binary type data...

Comment: UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc ]initWithData:data];
problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using `imageWithData:` to create your image, you should use `initWithData:` or just `[UIImage imageWithData:data]` instead of alloc'ing first.

Your code doesn't work because `imageWithData:` is a static method on UIImage that generates an autoreleased UIImage instance. Because it is a *static* method, not an instance method, it isn't a recognised selector on the UIImage *instance* you get when you call `[UIImage alloc]`

Answer (score 0):

as the error says the it's an unrecognized selector.

you should call - `(id)initWithData:(NSData *)data`.

`[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];`

or

`[UIImage imageWithData:data];`